# Updating progress bar in Webview when doing a file upload

Tags: android, file-upload, webview, progress-bar

I have noticed that when doing a file upload in Webview and using a progress bar, onProgressChanged is not called when the file upload takes place.

It looks like onProgressChanged is only being called when Webview is downloading content.
I understand that this is probably be design.

How can I track the progress of the file upload using Webview and visualize this using some kind of progress bar?

I have been trying to use a server progress bar but that did not work using Webview because of the following problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15474663/after-submit-form-updates-not-visible-in-webview-using-innerhtml

Comment: Why you ask again same question ?

Comment: It is not the same question! The first question is related to a server progress bar. This question is related to a progress bar using Android.